# 'newdata' had X rows but variables found have Y rowslonger

Tags: r, cross-validation

I am Trying to perform cross validation on 10 different models to select the optimal model. I followed one of the examples I saw earlier for 10 fold cross validation. After plotting, it looks like the conclusion of cross validation is wrong, which means my code is wrong. I am getting the below two errors/warnings. I looked at the similar error messages and they are talking about using different names. But I am not using any names.

My Questions are

1. Am I performing CV properly?
2. How do I fix these errors?

> 'newdata' had 957 rows but variables found have 9568 rowslonger
>
> object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Below is the code I wrote.

```
require(boot)
cv.error10 = rep(0, 10)
degree = 1:10
for(d in degree)
{
  glm.fit = glm(plant$PE~poly(plant$V, d), data=plant)
  cv.error10[d] = cv.glm(plant, glm.fit, K=10)$delta[1]
}
plot(degree, cv.error10)
lines(degree, cv.error10, type="b", col="red")
```

Comment: Just a guess, try removing the `plant$` parts from the `glm()` call.

Comment: @joran Damn, that worked without errors. Also, results of CV look logical. 
Could you expplain your guess on why it would work?

Comment: So the whole idea behind so many R modeling functions having a formula and data argument is that you construct the formula from JUST the column names, and then R looks for those objects in the data frame you pass to data. When a function has to reuse a formula from another call, all it sees is `plant$PE` it will literally grab that _entire_ column every single time in the cv function.

Comment: ...basically, you should never be doing `data$column` in a formula. In very simple cases it will work "by accident", but it will break in confusing ways otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.